# When using Caption Package, I receive: "Undefined control sequence \captionsetup "

Tags: packages, captions, installing, package-options, dtx

I introduce a figure as follows:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering

\includegraphics[scale=0.300]{Figure.eps}

\caption{Caption for the figure}
\label{a}

\end{figure}
```

In the preamble I have written:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font={small}}
```

I am writing the .tex file in Vim, in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. When I compile the .tex file writing in the terminal:

```
bash make_latex.sh
```

(script which link is here: http://www.mediafire.com/view/p6ha13gt53nilpv/make_latex.sh )

I receive this error:

[image]

I have installed manually the caption package following all these steps: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installing_Extra_Packages

**First Step**: I extracted the .ins file writing

```
latex caption.ins
```

The information generated in the terminal is here: https://www.mediafire.com/?o4giarg9jb4rov9

**Second Step**: As said in the instructions, I wrote:

```
latex caption.dtx
```

The information generated in the terminal is here: https://www.mediafire.com/?cl9ocvbid721p0a

**Third Step**: In `/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/caption` 
I copied the files that the info in the **First Step** told that were necessary to be copied. Here is the "proof":

[image]

**Fourth Step**: As said in the instructions, I made

```
texhash
```

And as it is shown here:

[image]

The process was done.

So, the question is: Why am I receiving that error when compiling ? I would appreciate very much if someone could help me

The latex version is:

[image]

Here is my entire preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\parindent 1 true cm
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eufrak}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[longnamesfirst,super]{natbib} 
\setcitestyle{square}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\pagestyle{fancy}                                        
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter .\ #1}{}}             
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection .\ #1}{}}
\lhead{\nouppercase}
\rhead{\nouppercase}
\fancyhead[LE]{{\sf \leftmark}}                             
\fancyhead[RE]{}
\fancyhead[RO]{{\sf \rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{}                                                
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}                                           
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{}                                                         
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}                                
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\captionsetup{font={small}}
\begin{document}
```

Comment: You should have installed `caption` with a suitable `apt-get` command. Did you run `sudo mktexlsr`?

Comment: First try `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended`

Comment: @egregI have just done: `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended`. The result is this: https://www.mediafire.com/?oy4czyk74kjtlws

Comment: So you already have `caption`. As far as I can remember, `\captionsetup` was already present in the version of `caption` available in 2009. Anyway, being five years behind is really too much, you should try upgrading your TeX Live.

Comment: @egreg I have made `bash make_latex.sh` but I receive the same `Undefined control sequence` error.

Comment: @egreg Ok,but even though with this version, a installation of a package like `caption` should function. Why is giving this error? Was installation made correctly ?

Comment: @DavidC.: Make sure you're using the correct (installed) version, and not some random copy identified via `mktexlsr`. See [Which package version am I using?](http://goo.gl/sBfU5X)

Comment: @Werner: I downloaded the Caption Package from CTAN, http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption . Was the installation made correctly or is there something wrong?

Comment: What happens if you type `\usepackage[font=small]{caption}` and omit the `\captionsetup` instruction?

Comment: @DavidC.: That's not what I said/asked. When you run `texhash`, TeX creates a hash table containing the folder structure where all accessible files are located. However, when you actually `\usepackage{caption}`, it may be that TeX grabs a file from your local working folder, or perhaps from a location that is different from `/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/caption`. That's why, adding `\listfiles` to your preamble and examining the location of the packages is important...

Comment: @Werner: Just added the `listfiles` in the preamble. Latex was grabbing a `.sty` from the folder where I am writing. I have removed that file, and have make sure there is no such `sty`s or similar package's files in any folder but the `/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/caption` Now it does not give that error. THANKS. BUT, BUT the battle is not ended (!!): there is a new problem: I have in the preamble: `\usepackage{caption}` followed by `\captionsetup{font=small,stretch={0.80}}`. I receive this error: https://www.mediafire.com/?v4tridr8acvg5i1

Comment: @Werner: There should not appear such error due to `stretch` is an option for this package: http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf

Comment: @DavidC.: You need `\usepackage{caption,setspace}` and then use `\captionsetup{font={small,stretch=0.80}}`, _not_ `\captionsetup{font=small,stretch=0.80}`.

Comment: @Werner: Yes indeed, in page 38 from http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf it is explained that it is possible to do what you have just said: `\captionsetup{font={small,stretch=0.80}}` , but it is needed the `setspcace` package. In page 10 from that document, it is said that `\setstretch{amount}` would make the same effect without installing the `setspace` package. -To be continued-

Comment: @Werner: Cont-.:  Well, I have tried: `\captionsetup{font={small,{\setstretch{0.80}}}}` but I receive this error: https://www.mediafire.com/?3o848ydeeai9yha I have also tried other combinations with this `\setspace{amount}` but no success; I receive the same error. How could I  correctly interpret the `\setstretch{amount}` in order that it works ?

Comment: @DavidC.: There is no mention of using `stretch` _without_ the [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package. So, add `\usepackage{setspace}` to your preamble.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on your setup, you may have different versions of packages floating around. When you're not sure what's going on with your version, it's best to [see what version of a package you're using](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13304/5764). Even though you think your TeXMF folder hash is updated, TeX may be grabbing something local, or something located elsewhere during the construction of the hash.

From the comments it seems like this was indeed the case (a local, outdated version).

---

In terms of your `font` selection inside `\captionsetup`. If you wish to use the `stretch` option, note that is should be supplied as part of the `font` setup:

```
\usepackage{caption,setspace}
\captionsetup{font={small,stretch=0.80}}
```

Comment: You should give your edition, which works for your answer.