# Image covers whole of a column and not at desired location

Tags: spacing, graphics, floats, vertical-alignment

I am new to Latex and want to insert a figure into my document. I used following commands:

```
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{PTS.eps}
\caption{Figure PTS}
\end{figure}
```

After compiling to pdf there is a large space between the figure and the caption. There is also a space of almost 5 lines at the top of figure. I am using 2 column format with 10 pt font and A4 size paper.
Please guide what should I do?

Regards
Ehsa

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: First, put an \fbox around your \includegraphics to see if the margin in in the picture itslef.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

What I've done with figures in the past is use a negative vspace in my document so that would yield something like:

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{PTS.eps}

\vspace{-0.3cm}
\caption{Figure PTS}
```

You would just have to play around with the value of the `\vspace` to whatever you want. Keep in mind a negative value will decrease the space and a positive will add more space.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But if I want the image to occupy both columns and keep text in two columns , what should be done.

Comment: @Ehsa `\begin{figure*}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{PTS} .... \end{figure*}`

Answer (score 0):

I initially used following command to look for the size of image
\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.150,angle=0]{imagefilename.eps}}

Then I used following to remove extra space in the image:
\includegraphics[scale=0.150,trim=300 450 300 500,clip]{imagefilename.eps}
It worked fine. Detailed information is given at following link
[An .eps image, whose caption is too separated from the image.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180060/an-eps-image-whose-caption-is-too-separated-from-the-image?rq=1)